# C++ Debug Assertion Failed Vector Subscript out of range

Tags: c++, vector

i've got some code that i've written using a 2d vector instead of a 2d array however when i go to run it all it says is "vector subscript out of range". any help is appreciated.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int mapx, mapy = 5;

vector<vector<int>> map(mapx, vector<int> (mapy, 0));

int i, x;

int main(){

for (i = 0; i < map.size(); i++){
    for (x = 0; x < map[i].size(); x++)
    {
        map[i][x] = i + x;
    }
}

cout << map[0][0];

cin >> i;
return 0;
}
```

Comment: `int mapx` isn't initialized. Looks like doing so fixes that: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/084aea611a4975d0

Comment: ok that last comment made me realize my error and it now works, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int mapx, mapy = 5;
```

This statement is not initialising both values to `5`: it's declaring two `int`s, initialising  `mapy` to `5` and leaving `mapx` uninitialized. Using `mapx` is undefined behaviour. Your entire `for` loop is skipped, and accessing `map[0][0]` is out-of-bounds.

You want this:

```
int mapx = 5, mapy = 5;
```